# TFS 2013 Build Definition in Git (how to associate build to commit)

Tags: git

What's the best way to track a build (a versioned binary) back to a commit in git.

Let's say the versioned binary is 1.0.1.0. I want to know exactly what commit that was built from. I realize that you can track it from TFS build history and then see the commit hash in the build history, but don't those get cleaned up?

In the past, I've done tags back into git to accomplish this, but am not finding a lot of resources on how to do this in an easy fashion (how would I even go about writing a script that TFS could run dealing with the authentication into git?)

I'm content with an easy way to trace it back to the hash in git, if that stays around in history. I didn't really want to go down the path of a custom build definition...

UPDATE:
The git source is hosted by TFS.